# add a column in data table using for loop

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` called `md` that looks like this

```
group_1 group_2
a       a
b       a
b       b
c       c
```

I use the following code:
 `groups <- c("group_1","group_2")`

```
    for (group in groups)
    {
     md[!get(group)=="a",get(group):="b"]
     md[,get(group):=factor(x = get(group),levels = c("a","b"),ordered = T)]
    }
```

So I want for both columns in the `data.table` if the value for every row is not "a" then replace the value with "b" and then add ordered levels to it.

But I get an error `Error in get(group): object 'group_1' not found`

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `get(group) :=` should be just `group := `

Comment: but then it adds a column called `group`, whereas i want to replace the values at the existing columns

Comment: It needs `(group) :=`

Comment: it worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `set`

```
 for(group in groups){
   set(md, i = which(md[[group]] !='a'), j = group, value = 'b')
    set(md, i = NULL, j = group, value = factor(md[[group]], levels = c('a', 'b'),
      ordered = TRUE))
}
md
#    group_1 group_2
#1:       a       a
#2:       b       a
#3:       b       b
#4:       b       b
```